# How do Iceblight and Waterblight affect Prowlers?

Tags: monster-hunter-generations

Both blights normally affect hunters in some way related to their stamina, but since Prowlers have no stamina, how are they affected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Waterblight makes your run speed slower.

Prowlers normally have three dodges they can do in a row, a bit like Lances, where the first two are normal dodges and the third has a longer animation. Iceblight removes the first two, making it more difficult to dodge as you can't do it as quickly.